# Cerberus/regex bottlenecking - Performant validation practices

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, performance, validation

I'm using AIOHTTP for a web app. I'm using Cerberus to validate user input. I ran some tests with wrk benchmark tool and found that the following Cerberus validator:

```
"uri": {
        "type": "string",
        "coerce": str,
        "required": True,
        "minlength": 1,
        "maxlength": 255,
        "regex": "^[a-zA-Z0-9/_]+$"
    }
```

adds about 10-15% of load time to web pages. That's borderline unacceptable to me. How to approach this problem? Is it just the regex engine? Is there a module known to be faster? I know string parsing functions are generally faster than regex. Is there a validation engine that doesn't use regex? A tool to convert regex to string parse would be interesting.

Edit: I ran a profiler:

```
from cerberus import Validator
from speed_profiler import SpeedProfiler
from pprint import pprint

def referer_validator(value):
    if len(value) < 1 or len(value) > 256:
        return False
    if not any(not l.isalnum() and l not in ['_', '/'] for l in value):
        return False
    return True


v = Validator()
v.schema = {
    "path": {
        "type": "string",
        "coerce": str,
        "required": True,
        "minlength": 1,
        "maxlength": 255,
        "regex": "^[a-zA-Z0-9/_]+$"
    }
}

sp = SpeedProfiler('Cerberus')

v.validate({'path': '/some/path_foo'})

sp.mark('Parser Function')

referer_validator('/some/path_foo')

profile = sp.stop()
pprint(profile)
```

which confirms that Cerberus is slow:

```
[{'duration': 0.00029901403468102217,
  'identifier': 'Cerberus',
  'line_num': 27,
  'percent_time': 98.26},
 {'duration': 5.29497629031539e-06,
  'identifier': 'Parser Function',
  'line_num': 31,
  'percent_time': 1.74}]
```

This confirms that Cerberus is slow. For now, I am using this for better speed:

```
def path_valid(value):
    if len(value) < 1 or len(value) > 256:
        return False
    if not any(not l.isalnum() and l not in ['_', '/'] for l in value):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: I have tried to follow the [documentation](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#regex), please try https://pastebin.com/c1YNk4yr. Tested [here](https://ideone.com/jRFhEF).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the function with `check_with` schema but still experience the slowdown. I think Cerberus is causing extra lag with any schema. That was a good try though and I prefer to use it over regex. I'm going to run a profiler and update question with more detailed findings.

Comment: Question updated with profile and possible solution (Your function) @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Just occurred to me it should be `len(value) > 255`

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use a non-regex solution you may use

```
def path_valid(value):
    if len(value) < 1 or len(value) > 255:
        return False
    if not any(not l.isalnum() and l not in ['_', '/'] for l in value):
        return False
    return True
```

This method fails the validation if the length of the value is less than 1 or more than 255 (due to `if len(value) < 1 or len(value) > 255` check) and failure will occur if there is a char that is not alphanumeric and not a `_` or `/` (check done with `if not any(not l.isalnum() and l not in ['_', '/'] for l in value)`).

See a [Python test here](https://ideone.com/jRFhEF).